Hash-based Polynomial Commitment Scheme for Small Polynomials
I am building a SNARK project which needs to use PCS (polynomial commitment scheme). Because of some constraints, I want the field of PCS to have no additional structures and thus I only want to use hash-based PCS. I find that there are two types of hash-based PCS, Breakdown PCS and FRI PCS.
However, I need to use PCS for small polynomials e.g. of the size from 2^12 to 2^20.
I find hash-based PCS performance very poor at this size, even worse than directly sending the polynomial for some parameters.
So I wonder whether there are techniques to solve this problems or there are fundamental limits of hash-based PCS for small polynomials?
